# having issues using face detection API from Clarifai API

Tags: css, reactjs, clarifai, tachyons-css

I have added the face detection API from Clarifai APi to my project, however, whenever i copy an image to my project and click on detects, it actually shows the image but it is not detecting the face.
see below App.js and FaceRecognition.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Clarifai from 'clarifai';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo';
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
import FaceRecognition from './components/FaceRecognition/FaceRecognition';
import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';
import './App.css';

const app = new Clarifai.App({
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      imageUrl: '',
      box: {}
    }
  }

  calculateFaceLocation =(data) => {
     const clarifaiFace = data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
     const image = document.getElementById('inputimage');
     const width = Number(image.width);
     const height = Number(image.height);
     return {
      leftCol: clarifaiFace.left_col * width,
      topRow: clarifaiFace.top_row * height,
      rightCol: width - (clarifaiFace.right_col * width),
      bottomRow: height - (clarifaiFace.bottom_row * height)
     }
  }

  displayFaceBox = (box) => {
    console.log(box)
    this.setState({box: box});
  }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({input: event.target.value})
  }

  onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input})
    app.models.predict(
      Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL,
      this.state.input)
      .then( response => this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(response)))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
      
  }

  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
       
       <Navigation />
       <Logo />
       <Rank />
       <ImageLinkForm  
       onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
       onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit} />
       <FaceRecognition box={this.state.box} imageUrl={this.state.imageUrl}/>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

FaceRecognition.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './FaceRecognition.css';

const FaceRecognition = ({imageUrl, box}) => {
    return (
      <div className='center ma'>
      <div className='absolute mt2'>
        <img id='inputimage' alt='' src={imageUrl} width='500px' height='auto' />
        <div className='bounding-box' style=
        {{top: box.topRow, right: box.rightCol, bottom: box.bottomRow, left: box.leftCol}}></div>
       </div>
     </div>
    );
}

export default FaceRecognition;
```

FaceRecognition.css

```
bounding-box {
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #149df2 inset;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

what am i doing wrong?
i tried copy paste from the actual Clarifai API code, but no luck
the bounding-box css is not even showing up in the console.
please help me

Comment: can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please don't use this client: https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-javascript, it has been deprecated for a while and several things in this package are very old and broken.

If you're purely developing client-side, you can use the REST endpoints directly: https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/predict/images (see "Javascript (REST)" snippets throughout the docs)

I also recommend to use PAT instead of API keys. This will allow you access across all your Clarifai apps with a single token.

Answer (score 0):

Clarifai has changed the way to use their Api. On Clarifai Face detect model , click to use model, then you can copy the code on how to use their Api.
https://clarifai.com/clarifai/main/models/face-detection?utm_source=clarifai&utm_medium=referral&tab=versions

Then you can import your PAT and other credentials requested for in the code from Clarifai portal.
Use this as a guide https://help.clarifai.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408131744407-Integrating-Clarifai-in-your-React-Javascript-project

You are welcome